# Office-js: Clearing discontinuous cells in different sheets causes performance issue

Tags: excel, office-js

I've the code to clear the discontinuous cells in different sheets in a Excel.
The issue is that when I've one or more Excel workbooks open in the background, the `context.sync()` call after clearing the cells in `ClearContents` function takes 2x longer compared to the previous iteration on the previous workbook. It keeps on growing 2x for every new workbook that's opened.

Following is the code snippet for the same:

```
async Func1(){
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    await this.ClearCells(context);
  });
}

async ClearCells(context: Excel.RequestContext) {
 const RangeArray = new Array<Excel.Range>();
 for (let i = 0; i < namedRanges.length; i++) {
    const range = this.getRange(context, namedRanges[i]);
    RangeArray.push(range);
 }
 await this.ClearContents(context, RangeArray,true);     
}

getRange(context: Excel.RequestContext, cellNamedRange: string){
 try {
  const names = workbook.names;
  const name = names.getItemOrNullObject(cellNamedRange);
  const range = name.getRange();
  return range;
 } catch (e) {
  return null;
 }
}

async ClearContents(context: Excel.RequestContext, Ranges: Array<Excel.Range>,clearformatting:boolean) {
 if (Ranges == null || Ranges.length == 0)
  return;
 for (var i = 0; i < Ranges.length; i++) {
  Ranges[i].load({ formulas: true, address: true });
 }

 await context.sync();
 for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
  if (ranges[i] != null && (!isnullorundefined(ranges[i].formulas[0][0]) && ranges[i].formulas[0][0] == '')) {
    ranges[i].clear(excel.clearapplyto.contents);
    if (clearformatting)
      ranges[i].clear(excel.clearapplyto.formats);
    ranges[i].untrack();
  }
 }
 await context.sync(); //takes 2x times more compared to every last iteration 
}
```

I've also tried using `RangeAreas` to clear all at once but it didn't make any difference in the execution time. I don't have any clue and stuck at the issue.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.